# Create columns based on many conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame who looks like this:

```
Id   Col1    Col2     Col3   Col4
1     1        1       1      0
2     1        0       1      0
3     0        1       1      0
4     1        1       0      1
5     1        1       1      nan
...
```

The col4 is the only that has nan values

So, I have multiple conditions to create multiple columns, for example:

```
New column A1
IF Col1 = 1 AND Col2 = 1 AND Col3 = 1
   AND (Col4 is null OR col4 = 0)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
New column A2
IF Col1 = 1 AND Col2 = 1 AND Col3 = 0
   AND (Col4 > 0)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
New column A3
IF Col1 = 1 AND Col2 = 1 AND Col3 = 0
   AND (Col4 is null OR col4 = 0)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
New column A4
IF Col1 = 1 AND Col2 = 0 AND Col3 = 1
   AND (Col4 > 0)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
New column A5
IF Col1 = 1 AND Col2 =01 AND Col3 = 1
   AND (Col4 > 0)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
```

I'm using the below code to create the new columns

```
A1_Conditions = [
    (df['col1'] ==1) & (df['col2'] == 1) & (df['col3'] == 1)
    &((df['col4'] ==0) | (df['col4'].isnull()))
]
First_Count['A1'] = np.select(A1_Conditions, [1], 0)
```

And it works but there are many columns to create and it's getting complicated to read

Is there other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

One idea with reuse conditions and if want assign `0,1` you can cast mask to integers or use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
mcol1_1 = df['col1'] == 1
mcol2_1 = df['col2'] == 1
mcol3_1 = df['col3'] == 1
mcol3_0 = df['col3'] == 0
mcol4_0 = df['col4'] == 0
mcol4_na = df['col4'].isnull()
mcol4_more0 = df['col4'] > 0
```

---

```
df['A1'] = (mcol1_1 & mcol2_1 & mcol3_1 & (mcol4_0 | mcol4_na)).astype(int)
df['A2'] = (mcol1_1 & mcol2_1 & mcol3_0 & mcol4_more0).astype(int)
...
...
```

```
df['A1'] = np.where(mcol1_1 & mcol2_1 & mcol3_1 & (mcol4_0 | mcol4_na), 1, 0)
df['A2'] = np.where(mcol1_1 & mcol2_1 & mcol3_0 & mcol4_more0, 1, 0)
...
...
```

```
df['A1'] = (mcol1_1 & mcol2_1 & mcol3_1 & (mcol4_0 | mcol4_na)).view('i1')
df['A2'] = (mcol1_1 & mcol2_1 & mcol3_0 & mcol4_more0).view('i1')
...
...
```